# Input to reshape is a tensor with 1382400 values, but the requested shape has 43200

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am building a neural network model using softmax regression to classify weather images I have 11 classes but the problem is whenever I run the model function it gives me the error above and I have tried changing the parameters in the initialization function and still giving the same error I figured it might be in the total_loss function as I am using this `total_loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits, from_logits=True))`  but still no progress however I will post the model below for your reference

```
def model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learning_rate = 0.0001,
          num_epochs = 1500, minibatch_size = 32, print_cost = True):
    """
    Implements a three-layer tensorflow neural network: LINEAR->RELU->LINEAR->RELU->LINEAR->SOFTMAX.
    
    Arguments:
    X_train -- training set, of shape (input size = 12288, number of training examples = 1080)
    Y_train -- test set, of shape (output size = 6, number of training examples = 1080)
    X_test -- training set, of shape (input size = 12288, number of training examples = 120)
    Y_test -- test set, of shape (output size = 6, number of test examples = 120)
    learning_rate -- learning rate of the optimization
    num_epochs -- number of epochs of the optimization loop
    minibatch_size -- size of a minibatch
    print_cost -- True to print the cost every 10 epochs
    
    Returns:
    parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. They can then be used to predict.
    """
    
    costs = []                                        # To keep track of the cost
    train_acc = []
    test_acc = []
    
    # Initialize your parameters
    #(1 line)
    parameters = initialize_parameters()

    W1 = parameters['W1']
    b1 = parameters['b1']
    W2 = parameters['W2']
    b2 = parameters['b2']
    W3 = parameters['W3']
    b3 = parameters['b3']

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)
    
    # The CategoricalAccuracy will track the accuracy for this multiclass problem
    test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
    train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
    
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((X_train, Y_train))
    test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((X_test, Y_test))
    
    # We can get the number of elements of a dataset using the cardinality method
    m = dataset.cardinality().numpy()
    
    minibatches = dataset.batch(minibatch_size).prefetch(8)
    test_minibatches = test_dataset.batch(minibatch_size).prefetch(8)
    #X_train = X_train.batch(minibatch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(8)# <<< extra step    
    #Y_train = Y_train.batch(minibatch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(8) # loads memory faster 

    # Do the training loop
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        epoch_total_loss = 0.
        
        #We need to reset object to start measuring from 0 the accuracy each epoch
        train_accuracy.reset_states()
        
        for (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) in minibatches:
            
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                # 1. predict
                Z3 = forward_propagation(tf.transpose(minibatch_X), parameters)

                # 2. loss
                minibatch_total_loss = compute_total_loss(Z3, tf.transpose(minibatch_Y))

            # We accumulate the accuracy of all the batches
            train_accuracy.update_state(minibatch_Y, tf.transpose(Z3))
            
            trainable_variables = [W1, b1, W2, b2, W3, b3]
            grads = tape.gradient(minibatch_total_loss, trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, trainable_variables))
            epoch_total_loss += minibatch_total_loss
        
        # We divide the epoch total loss over the number of samples
        epoch_total_loss /= m

        # Print the cost every 10 epochs
        if print_cost == True and epoch % 10 == 0:
            print ("Cost after epoch %i: %f" % (epoch, epoch_total_loss))
            print("Train accuracy:", train_accuracy.result())
            
            # We evaluate the test set every 10 epochs to avoid computational overhead
            for (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) in test_minibatches:
                Z3 = forward_propagation(tf.transpose(minibatch_X), parameters)
                test_accuracy.update_state(minibatch_Y, tf.transpose(Z3))
            print("Test_accuracy:", test_accuracy.result())

            costs.append(epoch_total_loss)
            train_acc.append(train_accuracy.result())
            test_acc.append(test_accuracy.result())
            test_accuracy.reset_states()


    return parameters, costs, train_acc, test_acc
```

EDIT: full trace error

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-438f3af55d6e> in <module>
----> 1 parameters, costs, train_acc, test_acc = model(new_train, new_y_train, new_test, new_y_test, num_epochs=100)

<ipython-input-16-d7361440d582> in model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learning_rate, num_epochs, minibatch_size, print_cost)
     58         train_accuracy.reset_states()
     59 
---> 60         for (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) in minibatches:
     61 
     62             with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in __next__(self)
    812   def __next__(self):
    813     try:
--> 814       return self._next_internal()
    815     except errors.OutOfRangeError:
    816       raise StopIteration

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in _next_internal(self)
    775     # to communicate that there is no more data to iterate over.
    776     with context.execution_mode(context.SYNC):
--> 777       ret = gen_dataset_ops.iterator_get_next(
    778           self._iterator_resource,
    779           output_types=self._flat_output_types,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py in iterator_get_next(iterator, output_types, output_shapes, name)
   3026       return _result
   3027     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
-> 3028       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   3029     except _core._FallbackException:
   3030       pass

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6654 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   6655   e.message += (" name: " + str(name if name is not None else ""))
-> 6656   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   6657 
   6658 

InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 1382400 values, but the requested shape has 43200
     [[{{node Reshape}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext] name:
```

Comment: Please share the full error backtrace

Comment: @YakovDan Done.

Comment: It's still not very clear. Can you create a [minimal reproducible example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your question?